# when i tried to convert my xlsx file to csv then "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space"

Tags: java

here is the code

```
package com.simplecode.excel;

import java.io.File;


import java.io.FileInputStream;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class XlstoCSV {

    static void xlsx(File inputFile, File outputFile) {

        // For storing data into CSV files

        StringBuffer data = new StringBuffer();


        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

            // Get the workbook object for XLSX file

            XSSFWorkbook wBook = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(inputFile));
            // Get first sheet from the workbook

            XSSFSheet sheet = wBook.getSheetAt(0);

            Row row;

            Cell cell;

            // Iterate through each rows from first sheet

            Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();

            while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {

                row = rowIterator.next();

                // For each row, iterate through each columns
                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

                data.append("\r\n");

                while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {

                    cell = cellIterator.next();

                    switch (cell.getCellType()) {

                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:

                            data.append(cell.getBooleanCellValue() + ",");




                            break;

                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:

                            data.append(cell.getNumericCellValue() + ",");

                            break;

                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                            data.append(cell.getStringCellValue() + ",");

                            break;

                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:

                            data.append("\r\n" + ",");
                            break;

                        default:
                            data.append(cell + ",");

                    }
                }
            }

            fos.write(data.toString().getBytes());

            fos.close();


        } catch (Exception ioe) {

 ioe.printStackTrace();

        }
    }

    //testing the application 


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //reading file from desktop

        File inputFile = new File("C:/Users/1479420/Desktop/Book1.xlsx");

        //writing excel data to csv 

        File outputFile = new File("C:/Users/1479420/Desktop/Book.csv");

        xlsx(inputFile, outputFile);
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of `data.append` print the content and see if it ends, in case it does - it means that the data is too big to be appended using `StringBuffer` (you can try `StringBuilder` which is more recommended by the way). If it doesn't end - you'll see from the printing where it's getting stuck.

Comment: if i will remove data.append it will print in a same row

Comment: so you got your answer, you're failing cause you're using `StringBuffer`

Comment: @alfasin i have a file of 3 mb size. even after changing stringbuffer to stringbuilder its saying same exception

Comment: So don't use neither :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use BufferedWriter instead of FileOutputStream and write data directly to BufferedWriter, dont use StringBuffer